# Maven Spring Boot trying to connect to MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to connect my web application to MySQL. Spring Boot is not detecting the database but can connect to the server. Can someone lead me in the right direction so it can detect the schema. With the @Entity annotation, it should auto create a table in the database as "User". It should also say in the console "Database available" I have tried looking online but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated!

[image: Here is my MySQL Workbench Showing the schema is there]

This is my application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/espersdb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

This is my console

```
2020-12-27 03:32:47.859  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] c.D.E.E.EspersWebsiteApplication         : Starting EspersWebsiteApplication using Java 14.0.2 on DESKTOP-01JT4QR with PID 26012 (C:\Users\Donobuz\Documents\Espers_Website\target\classes started by Donobuz in C:\Users\Donobuz\Documents\Espers_Website)
2020-12-27 03:32:47.862  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] c.D.E.E.EspersWebsiteApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-12-27 03:32:47.913  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2020-12-27 03:32:47.913  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2020-12-27 03:32:48.510  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2020-12-27 03:32:48.511  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JDBC repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-12-27 03:32:48.516  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 3 ms. Found 0 JDBC repository interfaces.
2020-12-27 03:32:48.523  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2020-12-27 03:32:48.523  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-12-27 03:32:48.529  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 0 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-12-27 03:32:48.830  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.hateoas.config.HateoasConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.hateoas.config.HateoasConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-27 03:32:48.833  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'relProviderPluginRegistry' of type [org.springframework.plugin.core.support.PluginRegistryFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-27 03:32:48.839  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'relProviderPluginRegistry' of type [org.springframework.plugin.core.OrderAwarePluginRegistry] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-27 03:32:48.842  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean '_relProvider' of type [org.springframework.hateoas.server.core.DelegatingLinkRelationProvider] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-27 03:32:48.847  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'messageResolver' of type [org.springframework.hateoas.mediatype.MessageSourceResolver] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-27 03:32:48.848  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.data.web.config.SpringDataJacksonConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.data.web.config.SpringDataJacksonConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-27 03:32:48.851  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'jacksonGeoModule' of type [org.springframework.data.geo.GeoModule] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-27 03:32:48.861  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.rest.RepositoryRestMvcAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.rest.RepositoryRestMvcAutoConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-27 03:32:48.863  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-27 03:32:48.864  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizerConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizerConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-27 03:32:48.872  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'spring.jackson-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonProperties' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonProperties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-27 03:32:48.873  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'standardJacksonObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizerConfiguration$StandardJackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-27 03:32:48.875  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$ParameterNamesModuleConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$ParameterNamesModuleConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-27 03:32:48.876  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'parameterNamesModule' of type [com.fasterxml.jackson.module.paramnames.ParameterNamesModule] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-27 03:32:48.877  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-27 03:32:48.881  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'jsonComponentModule' of type [org.springframework.boot.jackson.JsonComponentModule] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-27 03:32:48.883  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' of type [org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-27 03:32:48.888  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'spring.data.rest-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.rest.RepositoryRestProperties' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.rest.RepositoryRestProperties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-27 03:32:48.889  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'springBootRepositoryRestConfigurer' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.rest.SpringBootRepositoryRestConfigurer] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-27 03:32:48.890  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'configurerDelegate' of type [org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestConfigurerDelegate] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-27 03:32:48.896  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration$StringHttpMessageConverterConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration$StringHttpMessageConverterConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-27 03:32:48.902  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'stringHttpMessageConverter' of type [org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-27 03:32:48.903  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration$MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverterConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration$MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverterConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-27 03:32:48.903  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-27 03:32:48.907  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' of type [org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-27 03:32:48.929  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'jacksonObjectMapper' of type [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-27 03:32:48.934  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter' of type [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-27 03:32:48.935  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-27 03:32:49.190  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-12-27 03:32:49.197  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-12-27 03:32:49.197  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.41]
2020-12-27 03:32:49.278  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-12-27 03:32:49.279  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1364 ms
2020-12-27 03:32:49.512  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-12-27 03:32:49.546  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.25.Final
2020-12-27 03:32:49.620  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2020-12-27 03:32:49.682  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-12-27 03:32:49.924  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-12-27 03:32:49.933  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
2020-12-27 03:32:50.049  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-12-27 03:32:50.056  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-12-27 03:32:50.135  WARN 26012 --- [  restartedMain] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2020-12-27 03:32:50.374  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-12-27 03:32:50.954  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@6707114e, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@20e3d55, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@10647f40, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@17135eb0, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@297f9882, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@21beac54, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@2741bf4a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@425f1341, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@5e42e0a, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@7df3f08, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@51e53a6e, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@666fe17e, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@46a96507, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@7edc01a5, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@460056c3]
2020-12-27 03:32:51.017  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 8081
2020-12-27 03:32:51.050  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-12-27 03:32:51.059  INFO 26012 --- [  restartedMain] c.D.E.E.EspersWebsiteApplication         : Started EspersWebsiteApplication in 3.585 seconds (JVM running for 4.305)
2020-12-27 03:33:11.148  INFO 26012 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-12-27 03:33:11.149  INFO 26012 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-12-27 03:33:11.151  INFO 26012 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 2 ms
```

This is my DTO / Entity

```java
package entities;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import java.time.Instant;

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Long userID;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    @Email
    private String email;
    private Instant createdDate;
    private boolean enabled;
}
```

My User Repository

```java
package repos;

import entities.User;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

Lastly, this is my pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.Donobuz.Espers</groupId>
    <artifactId>Espers_Website</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Espers_Website</name>
    <description>A web application with many features to help gamers</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.22</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out the answer:
I must declare `spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true` in the application properties as well. This then created the specified table correctly with correct columns

Answer (score 0):

Try this `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I have tried that already before posting a question here. That did not work.

Comment: it does not unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

you please append some property in URL ( if you want to generate database automatically)

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/espersdb?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true   

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name="User")    // missing in your code
public class User {
//blah blah
}
```

Comment: I actually got an error using @Table annotation. Using @Entity(name="") works better and throws no error.

Comment: are you importing "javax.persistence.Table" package?